# Cartesian product using python without itertools

Tags: python

I came across this nice line of python code for cartesian product of n number of lists that I would like to bring back on multiple lines :

```
def cart_product_1(*seqs):
    if not seqs:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [[x] + p for x in seqs[0] for p in cart_product_1(*seqs[1:])]
```

This seemed pretty straightforward to me, but obviously I'm missing something here. I'm thinking I need to append a list somewhere but can't quite figure it out.

```
def cart_product_1(result,*seqs):
    if not seqs:
        return [[]]
    else:
        for x in seqs[0]:                       
            for p in cart_product_1(result,*seqs[1:]):
                 result.append([x]+p)
        return result
```

This leads to a MemoryError.

Comment: Instead of `return[[x]+p]` try doing `prodList.append([x]+p)` and return the prodList after the two loops. Don't forget to initialize prodList in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line in your example is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Basically, the one line is constructing a list *and* calculating its members.

To do the same thing, you have to add an initializer and return:

```
result = []
for x in seqs[0]:                       
    for p in cart_product_1(*seqs[1:]):
        result.append([x]+p)
return result
```

Comment: I'm getting a MemoryError, maybe it has to do with the rest of my code, I edited my question to add the first half of code

Comment: Where are you declaring `a`? OutOfMemory errors are notoriously hard to track down. You’ll probably want to read some other resources before tackling it.

Comment: I was declaring it out of the function, then I thought maybe IN the function, but since this is recursion it's going to declare every loop? Where CAN I declare it? Could I maybe pass "a" as a argument in the function? Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: As you currently have your code, it shouldn't be doing much of anything. If the original version you posted with the list comprehension works, then the version that I posted (with declaring `result` inside of the function) should work the exact same way. What you have now shouldn't be causing a memory error because you're actually returning much too early. Though, since you are only using one `result` variable maybe you are making it huge.

Comment: If I put the return result line back where you had it, then I get the MemoryError. I was trying to move things around to see if I could get it to work. I also added the result variable inside of the functions arguments cause I don't see how I can pass it into the recursion otherwise. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Putting the "result" variable inside the arguments was a mistake, instead I had to declare and and reinitialize it ouside of my if statement, but inside of my function.

Comment: You shouldn't need to put it outside of your if statement (if the code you have posted is accurate to your actual code). But in any case, I'm glad you've gotten it working.

Comment: I'm not sure where the best place to reinitialise it is, but I have to set it back to null everytime I enter or exit a new recursion or else it goes on to infinity.